# nodejs to client side parameters passing without exposing as window variable

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am using nodejs and ejs as the view template and mithril js as client side. To pass db result from node to client, i  am assigning that to a window variable in ejs and getting that in client side. Is this the correct way?. My data is exposing in script section of 'view page source' .which i don't want. Anybody please explain how to do it without making the data as browser window variable.

Nodejs:

var content = render(m.component(signin_component,{param: "abcd" }));

renderPage(resp, data: {param: 'abcd'});

ejs:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset="utf-8">
      window.data = '<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>';
</script>
```

Comment: Directly use ejs variable , if you assign it to js variable it will be exposed in page source. Otherwise try obfuscating your code.

Comment: I am mounting my component like ,  m.mount(element, m.component(component, JSON.parse(data)  ) ) .EJS variable is not availabe in client side mounting. data is undefined

Comment: I am not sure about mount. But when you can assign to window variable , u can also use variable directly., <℅-data.param℅>